# Use limit value at a point

Tags: matlab, limit

I have the following lines of code

```
arg1 = ( x<=a ).*(log(x)) + ( x>a).*(log(2*a-x));
num = sinh(arg1);
den = const + cosh(arg1);
re = num./den + const2;
re1 = ;
```

But `re` is not defined at x=0, as log blows up at 0. But re has a limiting value at 0 which is defined as const3.

I want `re1` as `const3` when x=0 and as re when x>0.
I tried using piecewise as

```
re1:= piecewise([x = 0, const3],[ x>0, re]);
```

But this does not work.
I get the error "Undefined function or method `re1` for input arguments of type `char`.

How should I get the desired result?

Comment: You'll also have problems with `(x>a).*(log(2*a-x))` in case `x > 2*a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use logical indexing:

```
re1 = re;
re1(x == 0) = const3;
```

and, even though it's probably "impossible", my experience tells me it's a good idea to do this as well:

```
re1(x >= 2*a) = const3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It gave the desired result.

Comment: @GouriMandal: Does your `x` ever exceed `2*a`? If so, you'll have problems also with the second part (logs of negative numbers are imaginary)

Answer (score 0):

You will need Symbolic Math Toolbox.
In general, if you define f(x) as a function and want to calculate the limit at x=a, you do as follow,

```
sym x
const3 = limit (sym (f),x,a)
```

This might help: http://www.mathworks.in/help/symbolic/limit.html

Comment: I actually have the limit. I just needed to use it in another array. Thanks for the answer!